# How do i add disabled=disabled attribute to <select> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

I have a html  field.

```
<select name="select-states" disabled="disabled"><option value="">Choose State &raquo;</option></select>
```

initially the field is disabled, i want to enable or disable it based on events. to enable it i am using the following jQuery which works fine.

```
$('select[name="select-states"]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

I want to re-enable it using jQuery, for which i tried using this which does not work.

```
$('select[name="select-states"]').attr('disabled');
```

What am i missing? which is the correct syntax for this?

thank you

Comment: I bet it took you more time to write that question than having a look at the documentation ;) http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: lol, i did see that documentation, but found it to be confusing :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your code, you provide only one parameter to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). This indicates that the function should just return the value for the `disabled` attribute of that element.

To set the `disabled` attribute, **provide the attribute name (first parameter) along with a value (second parameter)**:

```
$('select[name="select-states"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```